# Stream File to a Windows Service

Tags: file, windows-services, streaming

I have a windows service that needs to send an attachment through email. This service does not have access to the file location. So, I need to write something that the windows service will call and get the file stream from.

What is the best approach to accomplish this.

I have tried creating a webservice that will write the stream to the output stream of the request, but then i am having issues with calling the webservice.

Comment: What issues are you having calling the web service?  If the Windows service does not have access to the file but the web service does then the web service should be able to serve the file to the Windows service just fine.

Comment: if i call the method in the webservice, i would need to access the response stream, after the method is complete. Now there are two ways i can call the webservice
1. create an instance of the proxy and call the method on it, if i do this, i am not able to access the response object.
2. If i use a WebRequest, i would have access to the response object, but i dont know how to call the webmethod in the webservice, using this approach

Answer (score 0):

Is .NET remoting an option? You can send a base64 string through a .net remoting message and then process it when it is received by the service.